# Module not found on Jboss AS 7.1 Final

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I've deployed an ear file on Jboss 7.1 that uses some external modules.

I've added those modules as global modules in my standalone.xml file:

```
<global-modules>
    <module name="org.jboss.messaging" slot="main"/>
    <module name="com.oblicore" slot="main"/>
    <module name="org.infinispan" slot="main"/>
</global-modules>
```

but for some reason the first module doesn't seem to be recognized and i get this error:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at 

org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:163) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$1$1.runInvocation(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:71) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:73) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 | Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/jms/destination/JBossDestination
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at com.oblicore.manager.adapters.migration.handlers.MigrationHandler.bytesToMap(MigrationHandler.java:322) [MigrationToolAdapter-1.0.jar:1.0]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at com.oblicore.manager.adapters.migration.handlers.MigrationHandler.deserializeMsg(MigrationHandler.java:73) [MigrationToolAdapter-1.0.jar:1.0]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at com.oblicore.manager.adapters.migration.MigrationAdapter.startMigrationAdapter(MigrationAdapter.java:53) [MigrationToolAdapter-1.0.jar:1.0]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at com.oblicore.manager.adapters.migration.scheduler.MigrationAdapterAction.execute(MigrationAdapterAction.java:46) [MigrationToolAdapter-1.0.jar:1.0]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:104) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   ... 23 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.jms.destination.JBossDestination from [Module "org.jboss.messaging:main" from local module loader @176cad3 (roots: C:\Program Files\Oblicore\JBOSS7\modules)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |   ... 47 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/22 16:43:22 |
```

The missing class is definitely in the jar that is found in this module. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to finally solve it with some help from someone from the Jboss community.

You can see the answer here: https://community.jboss.org/message/737218#737218

Basically I turned on TRACE logging on the modules and saw that I'm actually missing javax.jms.Destination, so I just added dependency to that module.